Calculate the angle $x$ in the quadrilateral $ABCD$
Calculate the angle $x$ formed by the diagonals of a quadrilateral given
$$\angle ABD = 50^o\\\angle EBC = 80^o \\ \angle BDA = 100^o \\ \angle BDC=30^o\\\angle CEB = x$$
(Answer:$60^o $)

My try:
$\angle DAB = 180^o - 150^o = 30^o $
$\angle BCD = 180^o - 110^o = 70^o $\
$ x = \angle EAB+50^o  = 30^o +\angle ACD = 100^o -\angle BCE=80^o -\angle DAE$
How do I finish?

Peta, why a non readable diagram?

It is impossible to read the values in the picture. Can you write them down, or upload a new picture?

can't read bro, is that 50 or an 80..can't tell.

@Moti I don't know why the figure is looking like this... I just paste the file... If anyone knows what could be happening;;;

@user376343 $\angle ABD = 50^o:\angle EBC = 80^o : \angle BDA = 100^o : \angle BDC=30^o\angle CEB = x $

It seems that someone did the solution:)


In the figure circles s and d have common chord CD so OF is perpendicular bisector of CD. We have:
$\overset {\huge\frown}{DH}=\overset {\huge\frown}{CN}$
$\Rightarrow \overset {\huge\frown}{NH}=\overset {\huge\frown}{CD}$
$\overset {\huge\frown}{CH}=20^o$
$\overset {\huge\frown}{NH}=\overset {\huge\frown}{CD}=40^o$
$\overset {\huge\frown}{NH}+\overset {\huge\frown}{AD}=2\times 50=100^o$
$\Rightarrow \overset {\huge\frown}{AD}=60^o$
$\overset {\huge\frown}{DAP}=2\times 70=140^o\Rightarrow \overset {\huge\frown}{AB_2}=140-60=80^o$
$\overset {\huge\frown}{B_2P}=20^o$
$\Rightarrow \overset {\huge\frown}{AB_2P}=100^o$
$\angle ELB=(\overset {\huge\frown}{AB_2P}+\overset {\huge\frown}{FH})/2=\frac{100+40}2=70^o$
$\Rightarrow \angle LEB=\angle DEF=60^o$
That is OF passes point E and EF is bisector of angle DEC, so we have:
$x=\angle FEC=\angle DEF=60^o $

Please introduce point after point the needed points (only) using constructions in some order that can be followed. In the given picture there are problems already after some few displayed relations. Yes,  we have $\overset {\huge\frown}{DH}=\overset {\huge\frown}{CN}=60^\circ$, because the arcs correspond to given inscribed angles of $30^\circ$. The claimed $$\overset {\huge\frown}{DH}=20^\circ$$ is false, it must be a typo, $\overset {\huge\frown}{CH}=20^\circ$, followed by the relation $$\overset {\huge\frown}{NH}=\overset {\huge\frown}{CD}=40^\circ\ .$$Why do we have these relations?

@dan_fulea, You are right, corrected..

I am trying to give more solutions to the present question. But first of all, there will be some comments, the solutions depend on them. The problem has a setting of the shape "Here is a picture of segments and given angles between them, find the $x$ angle from the picture!" There is no construction of the picture with the given angles. This is no problem - as long as the "picture"

first of all exists, so that we have a problem and no random value of $x$ is an answer,
then secondly if the picture is unique with given parameters, so that $x$ is unique.

Usually, this is the responsibility of the source.
If the problem comes from some book and the books gives only the picture, this is a bad book (mathematically, structurally, and as a matter of the missed didactic purpose). On a blackboard we may "have a problem", but then the person drawing the picture is exposed to questions. If no question comes, it is fine. In our case the original source is intermediated by a posted question. Many times i pointed out in similar situations that it is the duty of the poster to provide content. This means here: give the source, the level, the year, the author, if known; introduce objects one by one, so that the above two issues (existence and uniqueness "of the picture") are cleared, show the own progress (and sorry, the two obvious observations that use the
sum $180^\circ$ of angles in a triangle are no progress at all), specify what kind of a solution is wanted, mention/cite/link related results that may help.
I will explain now why we have the mentioned existence and uniqueness.
(The argument is simple, but is essential to have the property.)
We start with two arbitrary points $B,D$. In one half-plane w.r.t. the line $BD$ construct the point $A$ so that the angles in $B,D$ in $\Delta ABD$ are respectively $50^\circ$, $100^\circ$. In the other half-plane w.r.t. the same line construct the point $C$ so that the angles in $B,D$ in $\Delta CBD$ are respectively $30^\circ$, $80^\circ$. We have then the situation in the figure. Draw the segment $AC$. It intersects the line $BD$ in a point $E$. The parallel to $AD$ through $C$ intersects the line $BD$ in a point on the segment $BD$ (i.e. between $B$ and $D$), and the line $AC$ intersects the line $BD$ also in the region between the two mentioned parallels, so the point $E$ is also on the segment $BD$. (It is not enough to "see" or "draw". Be part of an olympiad contest, and see how the work is evaluated, and where the evaluation drops.)
The existence "of the picture" is thus shown.
The same argument shows the uniqueness.

In particular, if we start with some situation, extend it, and inside the final "extended picture" we find our picture as a part of the geometric structure, then we can take this situation as a starting point, and use properties from it. We can for instance start with a point $A'$, draw rays
$A'B'$, $A'C'$, $A'D'$ making angles of $10^\circ$, $20^\circ$ in between, possibly rearrange $C'$, $D'$ so that some angles match the final picture, and try to solve an other related problem. We can also try to draw a regular $18$-gon, draw all lines through two of its vertices, consider all intersection, and search for the given picture in this context.
This latter point will be in fact realized in a solution. Why so complicated? Well, it is not complicated, but a structural approach. And the structure is related to a regular $18$-gon. In fact, there is an obvious join between the stated problem and the many Adventitious Configurations. This wiki link
mentions:

Classifying the adventitious quadrangles (which need not be convex) turns out to be equivalent to classifying all triple intersections of diagonals in regular polygons. This was solved by Gerrit Bol in 1936.

So the adventitious quadrangle from our problem is part of a long list of known such structures.
Using a regular $18$-gon turns out to be a good structural way to proceed, if concurrences of its diagonals are already known. This approach has the advantage of understanding why and how such configurations appear. To be concrete, imagine you have this problem in an olympiad. You may search a long or short time for an auxiliary construction that solves the problem in few lines. This may work, and you win. Or not, and you fail. One cannot prepare for this situation, and this strategy. Not touching a problem in such conditions means complete failure. So i was educated to search for the pattern that always work, thus using regular polygons. And one can prepare for this!
When i answer with this solution (only), i usually get one vote at most.

As it is the case with the initial problem, the adventitious rolling stone, had also a "simple" solution, based on an auxiliary point, which acts as a "windmill" with an equilateral shape covered by three blades. It "moves" properties from one direction easily in other directions. This is usually the "accepted solution", and catches here a lot of votes. But note that this solution usually comes from insight from the other solution, that gets no votes. (One needs some more hours to eliminate from the regular polygon as many points as possible. The embedding of the initial picture in the regular polygon framework is not shown, how the auxiliary points were chosen then not mentioned.)

Finally, such problems have easy solutions based on trigonometry. Such solutions "break the geometry", and are usually rejected for human reasons. Note that one can also argue as follows. There is a geometric proof for a relation like $\sin20^\circ=2\sin10^\circ\cos10^\circ$. (And for all trigonometric relations, where angles are appearing in a suitable geometric setting.) So mentioning this for one or two "hard places", and working else as much as possible geometrically, should be also a valid geometric approach. If such an approach is wanted or not, is a main information that should be given in the question. (And in the many similar questions.)

I start now with the solutions in the order "easy to find to hard to find".
All three solutions have a common part, that is presented here. We have seen that up to rescaling (of the length of the segment $BD$) the given configuration exists and is unique. We start with it and go with implications in one direction: If it exists, then...
We draw a parallel through $C$ to $AD$, it intersects $AB$ in a point denoted by $X$. Then $
\widehat{BXC} =
\widehat{BAD} = 30^\circ
\widehat{BDC}$, so the quadrilateral $BXDC$ is cyclic. Draw it, its circumcircle, and mark by $\Omega$ its center. This circle will be denoted by its center, $\odot(\Omega)$. Let $Y\ne D$ be the second intersection point of this circle with the line $AD$. The angles in the pentagon $BXDYC$ (formed by sides and/or diagonals) are easily computed. (Let us see how. The angles in $\Delta BXC$ are clear, $130^\circ$ in $B$ as given, $30^\circ$ in $X$ as the  angle in $A$, $20^\circ$ in $C$ so that they sum up to $180^\circ$. Then
$
\widehat{XDB} = 
\widehat{XCB} = 
20^\circ$,
$
\widehat{BDC} = 
30^\circ$ as given,
the trapezium $DYCX$ is inscribed in a circle, so it is isosceles, $DX=CY$, and so
$
\widehat{YBC} = 
\widehat{DBX} = 
50^\circ$,
which implies
$
\widehat{DBY} = 
80^\circ-50^\circ=30^\circ=
\widehat{CDB} $.
This means that $DBCY$ is also an isosceles trapezium ($BD\|CY$).
Observe that the green chords are equal, $DX=XC=CY$. From these computations we see that a regular $18$-gon inscribed in $\Omega$ can be drawn, we use numbers modulo $18$ for its vertices as notations, and type $k'$ instead of $-k$ (modulo $18$) since it is easier to type. We arrange that the following matchings of the points $C,B,X,D,Y$ occur:
$$
C=0\ ,\qquad
B=3\ ,\qquad
X=5\ ,\qquad
D=10=-8=8'\ ,\qquad
Y=13=-5=5'\ .  
$$
The question has already used the notation $E$ for the intersection point fo the diagonally $AC,BD$ of the given quadrilateral. We cannot use it, and do not want to use it to have a clear distinction of the properties of the introduced points. So we define $E'$ as the intersection of the diameter $54'$, and the lines $BD=38'$, and $7C=70$, reflected in each other w.r.t. the diameter $54'$.
It remains to show that the lines $AC$ and $7C$ coincide. (In other words, that $A,7,C$ are collinear. This would imply $E=E'$, and we can easily read angles formed in $E$ now by chords of the circle intersecting here.)
So we have the following picture as a start, common for all three solutions that follow:

(Some of the points are not defined, they are specific for the one or the other solution. Note that we have so far no information about the fact that $E=E'$, that $A,7,C=0$ are collinear, that the angles in $A$ formed by the rays $AB$, $AC$, $AD$ are $10^\circ$ and $20^\circ$, as shown in the picture. The picture gives also a posteriori information. Some known angles, like the $100^\circ$ in $D$ in $\Delta ADB$, are not shown.)

(1) The trigonometric solution.
Easy level. We need only the initial picture.
We may and do assume that $BD= \sin30^\circ\sin70^\circ$.
In a triangle the sides are proportional to the sine values in the opposite angles. We know the angles in $\Delta DBA$ and $\Delta DBC$, so we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
BD &= \sin30^\circ\sin70^\circ\ ,\\
AB &= \sin100^\circ\sin70^\circ\ ,\\
AD &= \sin50^\circ\sin70^\circ\ ,\\
BC &= \sin30^\circ\sin30^\circ=\frac 14\ ,\\
CD &= \sin30^\circ\sin80^\circ\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Denote by $y$ the unknown angle in $A$ in $\Delta CAD$. Then we have:
$$
1
=\frac
{\quad\frac{AC}{\sin130^\circ}\qquad}
{\quad\frac{AC}{\sin130^\circ}\qquad}
=\frac
{\ \frac{BC}{\sin(30^\circ-y)}\ }
{\ \frac{CD}{\sin y}\ }
=\frac
{\ \frac{\sin 30^\circ\sin 30^\circ}{\sin(30^\circ-y)}\ }
{\ \frac{\sin 30^\circ\sin80^\circ}{\sin y}\ }
=\frac{\sin y}{2\sin(30^\circ-y)\cos 10^\circ}
\ .
$$
So $y$, an angle between $0^\circ$ and $30^\circ$, is a solution of the equation:
$$
\sin y - 2\sin(30^\circ-y)\cos 10^\circ=0\ .
$$
On the L.H.S. of the equation we have a function of $y$, defined on
the interval between $0^\circ$ and $30^\circ$, the function $y\to\sin y$ is increasing, the function $\sin(30^\circ-y)$ is decreasing, so the total expression on the L.H.S. is an increasing function. (To be strict, strictly increasing.) The value in $0^\circ$  is negative, the value in $30^\circ$ is positive. So there is exactly one solution in the wanted range. We simply verify that $y=20^\circ$ is a solution, this is so because of the formula for the double angle, $\sin(2z)=2\sin z\cos z$, applied for $z=10^\circ$.
So $\widehat{AED}$, computed in $\Delta AED$ is $180^\circ-y-100^\circ=60^\circ$.
$\square$

(2) The solution using the regular $18$-gon and its symmetries.
We need for it the long story that accompanies the above picture, describing how it was constructed, and how to recognize the vertices $C,B,X,D,Y$ as its vertices. Recall that we have defined $E'=BD\cap 07=BD\cap 07\cap X4'$ (by symmetry w.r.t. diameter $X4'=54'$) in the notations of the above picture.
We are showing $E=E'$. The chords $47'$ and $BD=38'$ are symmetric w.r.t. the diameter $72'$, so they intersect in a point on it, denoted by $V$,
so $V=72'\cap 47'\cap BD$.
The following Lemma defines a point $W=54'\cap 47\cap 61'\cap BD\cap 71$.
Consider now the similar triangles $\Delta W7V\sim\Delta XAD$. They have parallel sides by construction, explicitly, the following lines are parallel:
$7W=71\|53=AX$, and $7V=72'\|8'5'=AD$, and $WV=47'\|58'$.
So they are in perspective, and the perspectivity center is the known intersection of two lines connecting corresponding vertices, $5W\cap DW=E'$. So the third line connecting corresponding vertices, which is $A7$ also passes through $E'$. That means that on $7E'$ there are the points $A$ and $C=0$, so $E'$ is on $BD,AC$, so $E'=E$.
We have thus realized the wanted configuration in the framework of the regular $18$-gon $012\dots2'1'$, and of course there the angles around $E'$ can be easily red:
$$
\widehat{CEB} =
\widehat{CE'B} =
\frac 12\left(\overset{\huge\frown}{CB} + \overset{\huge\frown}{7D}\right)
=\frac 12(60^\circ+60^\circ)=60^\circ\ .
$$
$\square$
Proof of the used Lemma:
We want to show that in a regular $18$-gon the lines

$54'$ (supported by a diameter),
$47'$, $61'$ (reflected in each other w.r.t. $54'$
$39$, $71$ (reflected in each other w.r.t. $54'$

intersect in a point $W$. For this, here is an isolated picture:

Let $W$ be the intersection $W=39\cap 71$. Since
$3\leftrightarrow 7$,
$1\leftrightarrow 9$,
(reflections w.r.t. the diameter $54'$) this intersection $W$ is on the diameter $54'$. Let $\Omega$ be the center of symmetry of the $18$-gon. (The center of its circumcenter.) Then $\Delta 36\Omega$ is equilateral. One axis of symmetry of this triangle is the line $3W9$. W.r.t. it the points $6,\Omega$ are reflected in each other. The line $5W\Omega$ makes with the side $6\Omega$ of the blue equilateral triangle an angle of $20^\circ$. So it is reflected in a line through $6$ (reflection of $\Omega$) which makes with $6\Omega$ (the reflection of $\Omega 6$) also an angle of $20^\circ$. This is the line $61'$. So the diameter $54'$ (through $W$ on the reflexion axis) is reflected into $61'$. Which passes thus also through $W$.
$\square$

(3) The solution using a known lemma for the concurrence of three chords in a circle.
This lemma was important some $40$ years ago, as i prepared for the Olympiads.
It is part of the folklore, if i have to cite a source, then maybe the one most known is the book of Akopyan, Geometric figures, linked from his homepage as a first item. It has a section dedicated to regular polygons, where such intersections are mentioned. But it comes with no solution. In the meantime, there is a book "555 Geometry Problems..." of Stanislav Chobanov, Stanislav Dimitrov, Lyuben Lichev, where the solutions are present. In order to have a common scheme for such problems, this folklore lemma is mentioned as Problem 6.10.24:

Let $ABCDEF$ be a cyclic hexagon. Then the lines $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent iff $$AB\cdot CD\cdot EF = BC\cdot DE\cdot FA\ .$$

$\square$
(The proof in loc.cit. uses the sine version of Ceva.)
We can apply this lemma in our context. Recall the initial picture, which applies for all solutions. We want to show in it that starting from the regular $18$-gon $012\dots2'1'$ the following lines are concurrent (in a point $A$ in the given problem):
$$
35\ ,\quad
07\ ,\quad
5'8'\ .
$$
Taking the cyclic hexagon $ABCDEF$ from the cited lemma to be $305'578'$ we have, assuming a circumcircle with radius one:
$$
\begin{aligned}
BC\cdot DE\cdot FA 
&= 2\sin 50^\circ\cdot2\sin 20^\circ\cdot2\sin 70^\circ
\\
&= 2\sin 50^\circ\cdot2\sin 20^\circ\cdot2\cos 20^\circ
\\
&= 2\sin 50^\circ\cdot2\sin 40^\circ
\\
&= 2\cos 40^\circ\cdot2\sin 40^\circ
\\
&= 2\sin 80^\circ
\\
&= 2\sin 30^\circ\cdot 2\sin 80^\circ\cdot 2\sin 30^\circ
\\
&=AB\cdot CD\cdot EF\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

(4) This is (3) without sine values:
We easily reshape the above computation to not have any sines in the proof.
Let $R$ be the radius of the circumcircle of the regular $18$-gon.
Before we start the computation, let us focus the diameter $09$. Its length is $2R$. The distance from $5$ and $5'$ to it, denoted by $d(5,09)=d(5',09)$, is half of the segment $55'$, since $5$ reflects into $5'$ w.r.t. this diameter. Note also that the triangles $\Delta\,\Omega 57$ and $\Delta\, 38'4'$ are similar, both isosceles with an angle of $40^\circ$ between the equal legs. We write the proportionality of corresponding sides, and obtain
$\color{brown}{57\cdot 8'3=R\cdot 8'4'}$. So we can compute in the lemma using $ABCDEF$ as $305'578'$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{BC\cdot DE\cdot FA}{AB\cdot CD\cdot EF}
&=
\frac{05'\cdot \color{brown}{57\cdot 8'3}}{30\cdot 5'5\cdot 78'}
=
\frac{05'\cdot \color{brown}{R\cdot 8'4'}}{R\cdot 5'5\cdot R}
=
\frac{05'\cdot 5'9}{R\cdot 5'5}
\\
&=
\frac{2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta 05'9)}{R\cdot 5'5}
=
\frac{09\cdot d(5',09)}{R\cdot 5'5}
=
\frac{2R\cdot d(5',09)}{R\cdot 5'5}
=
\frac{2\cdot d(5',09)}{5'5}
=
\frac{5'5}{5'5}
\\
&=1
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

(5) One direct solution:
We start with the given configuration of points. And to be focused, we consider only the triangle $\Bbb T$ with vertices $B,C,D$, with known angles of respectively $80^\circ$, $70^\circ$, $30^\circ$.
Auxiliary construction: Let $\Omega$ be the circumcenter of $\Bbb T$, $R$ the circumradius of $\Bbb T$. Let $\Delta$ be the equilateral triangle with vertices $\Omega,B,C$ (isosceles, and the angle in $\Omega$ is twice $30^\circ$ in $D$), so $R=BC=\Omega B=\Omega C=\Omega D$. Then $D\Omega$ separates the $30^\circ$ angle in $D$
in $10^\circ=\widehat{CD\Omega }$,
and
$20^\circ=\widehat{\Omega DB}$.
Let $7=B'$ be the point which is the reflection (denoted by a prime $'$) of $B$ w.r.t. the perpendicular bisector of the segment $DC$. So $\Delta =\Delta BC\Omega$ is reflected into $\Delta'=\Delta 7D\Omega$.
Let $P,S$ be the intersections $P=D\Omega\cap C7$, $S=\Omega B\cap C7$.

Claim: $DS$ is the angle bisector in $\Delta \Omega DB$.
Proof: Let us first do the angle chasing for the values mentioned in the picture first. The given angles in $B,C$ in $\Bbb T=\Delta BCD$ are
$80^\circ$,
$70^\circ$, and after drawing the equilateral $\Delta$ we cut $60^\circ$ from each, so
$\widehat{\Omega CD}=10^\circ$,
$\widehat{\Omega BD}=20^\circ$. Same measures are copy+pasted in $D$, since $\Delta \Omega CD$, $\Delta \Omega BD$ are isosceles. So
$20^\circ = \widehat{BD\Omega}
 = \widehat{7C\Omega}
= \widehat{PC\Omega}
$, and $\widehat{PC\Omega}=10^\circ+10^\circ$, so $\Delta P\Omega C$ isosceles, making $P$ a point on the perpendicular bisector of $\Omega C$, which is the angle bisector in $B$ of $\Delta$, separating the angle in $B$ of $60^\circ$ in two orange $30^\circ$ angles.
We further compute two $40^\circ$ angles in $\Delta S\Omega P$, which is thus isosceles, and there  is one more
$40^\circ=60^\circ-20^\circ$ angle in $D$.
We note at this point the similarity $(*)$ to be used below:
$$
\Delta P\Omega C\sim\Delta 7DB\ .
$$
Let us show now the claim, which allows to mark two further $10^\circ$ angles in $D$, and we are close to the end. We compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{S\Omega}{SB}
&=
\frac{SP}{SB}
=
\frac{CP}{CB} \qquad\text{($BP$ bisects $\hat B$ in $\Delta BSC$)}
\\
&\overset{(*)}=
\frac{D7}{DB}
=\frac {D7}{D\Omega}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which shows the Claim.
$\square$
So $\widehat {DSB}=180^\circ -10^\circ-20^\circ=180^\circ -30^\circ$.
Now we can also include the point $A$ into the picture, where we know a $30^\circ$ angle, exactly the angle that makes $ADSB$ cyclic.

Then $\widehat{CSB}=80^\circ$ in $\Delta CSB$, and
$\widehat{BSA}=\widehat{BDA}=100^\circ$, the two angles add to $180^\circ$, so $A,S,C$ are colinear. It is now easy to locate $E=AC\cap BD$ in the picture, and the wanted angle $\widehat{CEB}$ in $\Delta CEB$ is $180^\circ-40^\circ-(20^\circ+30^\circ+30^\circ)=60^\circ$.


Produce $BC$ to $F$ so that $DCF$ is isosceles, and produce $BD$ to $G$ so that $\measuredangle BCG = 60^\circ$.
Since $\measuredangle DFC = 40^\circ$, and $\measuredangle DGC = 20^\circ$, $G$ lies on the circle centered in $F$ and passing through $D$ and $C$, which makes $CFG$ an isosceles triangle. However, $\measuredangle FCG = 60^\circ$, so that in fact $CFG$ is equilateral.
By construction and angle chasing, $DFB$ is isosceles, and $AB \perp DF$. Hence $ADBF$ is a kite, and $AFD$ is isosceles. Again we have $\measuredangle FDA = 60^\circ$, by construction, so that $AFD$ is equilateral as well, and $AFD \cong CFG$ (point 1. plus SSS criterion, e.g.).
By point 1., point 3., and SAS criterion we have $DCA \cong DCG$, which implies that $DEC$ is isosceles with $\measuredangle DEC = 120^\circ$. Therefore $$\boxed{BEC = 60^\circ.}$$
$\blacksquare$


